# php5.6でmysql_connectを使用したい。

Tags: php

ローカル環境でphp5.6,mysql5.6,Apacheの状態でmysql_connectを使用したいです。
サーバーにある古いコードをローカル環境で実行させたいのですが、mysql_connectが正常に動作しません。
サーバーのphpバージョンは5.6で、サーバーでは正常に動作しております。
ローカル環境はdockerで作成しておりまして、
**dockerfile**

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
RUN apt-get update && \
  docker-php-ext-install php-mysql mbstring
```

になります。「php-mysql」をインストールすれば使用可能かと思いましたが、現在も

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

のエラーが発生しております。

mysqliは使用しない為、mysql_connectで動作させる方法をご教授頂きたいです。

Comment: すみません、解決いたしました。dockerイメージをすべて削除し、dockerfileを「docker-php-ext-install mysql」に変更すると動作致しました。

Comment: 解決に至った情報はぜひ個別の回答として投稿してみてください。(このサイトでは自己回答も歓迎しています)